# SQL server trigger with interact other tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables. These are :

```
   PART TABLE                     CUSTOMER TABLE               ORDER TABLE
* PART_ID                      * CUST_ID                    * ORDER_ID
  PART_CODE                      CUST_CODE                    ORDER_DATE
  PART_NAME                      CUST_NAME                    CUST_ID
  PURCHASE_PRICE                 TOTAL_ORDER_QUANTITY         PART_ID
  SALES_PRICE                                                 QUANTITY
                                                              PRICE
```

So I have a few question:

1) When I insert order record to order table, part table must have that order's part id. Otherwise trigger should do rollback.

2) If there are at least 1 order record of part at ORDER table, that part can not delete.

This 2 operation should do with triggers. How can I do these 2 operation ?

I did following query for first question, but it didn't work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_IF_NOT_EXIST_PART
ON  [dbo].[ORDER]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ORDER] ON
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[ORDER]
    SELECT *
    FROM inserted II
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                        FROM PART P 
                            WHERE P.PART_ID = II.PART_ID)
END
```

Pseudo code of first operation (this is what I want to do in programming term)

```
boolean isFoundAtPartTable = false;
FOR EVERY ROW OF inserted TABLE {
    FOR EVERY ROW OF PART TABLE {
        IF (PART.PART_ID = inserted.PART_ID) {
            isFoundAtPartTable = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isFoundAtPartTable) {
        // so I can insert this record from inserted table to ORDER TABLE
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: These requirements do not need triggers which are usually used to **change** data in one table in response a change in another table. Your requirements only need additional WHERE clauses to make the checks.

Comment: a rolled-back transaction would undo ALL operations performed within the transaction, even those caused by triggers. a rollback should undo EVERYTHING you tried to do and leave the db exactly as it was before the transaction was started.

Comment: Instead of a trigger, why don't you use a foreign key constraint? Also, your syntax is not correct for MySQL. MySQL uses backticks around names, not square brackets. Square brackets are for SQL-Server.

Comment: Sorry about mysql tag. I removed it. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. And I added my scenarios pseudo code which is what I want.

Comment: The pseudo-code still looks like you are thinking back-to-front. When you go to do the insert in ORDER table, use the WHERE clause to check if the PART_ID is also in the PART table. If the WHERE clause fails, the INSERT won't be done at all. Doesn't need a trigger. As has been suggested, you could set up a foreign key constraint but then teh INSERT would fail with a database exception that you would have to handle. The effect would be the same.